# Light problems nwjs and threejs

Tags: dll, three.js, webgl, nw.js

I'm having problems with the lighting in my proyect, I'm just using normal direct light.

`light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xfefffe);`

But the problem is that with the 0.12.3 version of nwjs the objects in the scene are black (like if there was no lights) and sometimes the start flickering in red, black and green.
[image]
[image]

If I change the original libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll with the ones in the 0.13.0 version of nwjs it works fine but only in some hardware... I don't know whtas going on, what can I do to make everything work just fine?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what hardware limitation it seems. I used PowerVr device driver *.dll ( EGL and opengles ) for solution. Curious to know this problem happen on ubuntu/linux devices?
Since you are creating material which take light vector as input check on the basic material and see the result. 
Plus try to make the custom material shader which has (ambient,specular, (diffused optional) ) and then see result on machine.

Since the dll contains the implemenation of gles stuff onto window machine I believe you see this issue on window itself.

Black only comes when it require light vec into fragment shader and it is not been passed so texture2D result with light of undefined give you blackish output